# ExtJS ajax abort issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have a problem with `Ext.Ajax.abort()` function in Google Chrome.
Everything seems to be fine in FF the request gets aborted etc.
My function looks like this:

```
continousUpdateAjax= Ext.Ajax.request({
    params: { 
             object: this.fullObjectName                        
        },
    method: 'GET', 
    url: 'index.php?act=System_Act_ContinuousUpdate', 
    success: function (response) {
                        this.continousUpdateRestart();
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        this.continousUpdateRestart();
                    }
```

the restart function is fairly simple:

```
continousUpdateRestart: function(){
     Ext.Ajax.abort(this.continousUpdateAjax);
     continousUpdateAjax= null;
     this.getContinousUpdateRequest();
}
```

The `getContinousUpdateRequest()` just starts an ajax request. I also fire the restart function on grid reload. The php script sends DB queries every second for 1 minute and than ends. In firefox when I refresh grid I can see that the request was aborted and that only one was started when the current came back.
In Google chrome I don't see any aborts and for each request that was started a new one gets fired at the end(at first I thought that firebug might be wrong so i waited with 3 requests hanging and restart fired for each one of them).

Is this chrome issue or am I aborting in a wrong way?

Comment: You can use the autoAbort property